# Searching for match in different dataframe, then renaming columns to the match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with a set of tags and tagnames and a dataframe with columnnames by tags. The tag list is  175 items long, and the columnlist from input is 60 items long. I wish to rename the columnnames from tags to tagname. To do this I am doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df_input = pd.read_excel(r'C://Users//..//*.xlsx')
df_tags = pd.read_excel(r'C://Users//..//*.xlsx')
old_names = df_input.columns
new_names = []
tag = df_tags.iloc[:][0]


for i in range(0,len(df_input.columns)):
    for j in range(0,len(df_tags)):
        if df_input.columns[i] == df_tags.iloc[j][0]:
            new_names.append(df_tags.loc[j][1])

df_input.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)), inplace=True)
```

However, I am getting an Error like this:
KeyError: 'the label [122] is not in the [index]'

I do not understand which index label 122 is not found in, and how to fix this. Can anybody help?

Comment: I think you should use iloc instead of loc in the `new_names.append(df_tags.loc[j][1])` but it's hard guessing. Can you post part of df_input and df_tags?

Comment: When I do this, it does rename the columns in df_input, however it is not renamed by matches, but on a random fashion. But thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `pd.DataFrame.rename`

Avoid explicit `for` loops with Pandas. You can use [`pd.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with a series input:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]})
df_tags = pd.DataFrame({'in_col': ['A', 'C', 'D'], 'out_col': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']})

df_input = df_input.rename(columns=df_tags.set_index('in_col')['out_col'])

print(df_input)

   X  B  Y
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

The `rename` method is versatile and lenient. As described in the docs:

> Function / dict values must be unique (1-to-1). Labels not contained
>   in a dict / Series will be left as-is. Extra labels listed don’t throw
>   an error.

Comment: This works perfectly! Why should I avoid for loops with pandas? Thank you for you help :)

Comment: @solo12345, Because Python-level loops are slower than lower-level loops implemented internally by Pandas / NumPy.